# Stop automatic change of updatedAt timestamp while using .save() in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a collection in which the documents have an autogenerated `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields. Of course while updating any document, the `updateAt` timestamp also changes. I am aware of the `{ timestamps: false }` flag that I can pass to my update query from mongoose 5.9.3 onwards, but **I cannot use an update query for my current needs**.

For certain computations I have to find the element first, make changes to some fields and then manually use `document.save()` method to update the document (Yes I am aware of the concurrency issues that I will face, I have taken care of that separately). My only issue here is that I don't want to update the `updateAt` timestamp when I'm doing a .save(). Can anybody tell me what's the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I guess I should've read the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) more carefully! You can actually pass in the same `{ timestamps: false }` option in `.save()` as well and it will work just the way it does in an `update` query!

Mongoose is smart enough to track exact changes in your document and is able to construct an update query in the background for your operations, thus at the end of the day it's still a normal `update`

This piece of code should do the trick:

```
document.save({ timestamps: false })
```